# PyDrive and Files Not Found

Tags: python, file, pydrive

So I've noticed that PyDrive isn't able to find any files that weren't originally uploaded by PyDrive.

Using

```
myfilelist = drive.ListFile({'q': "'id' in parents and trashed=false"}).GetList()
```

it returns blank - but if I upload the file using PyDrive then it can find it.
Is this something to do regarding some kind of metadata that PyDrive leaves behind? Or am I completely missing something here?

Cheers

Comment: This is probably due to authentication. Are you sure you are using the same account to upload through pydrive and to open the browser? In my case, Im using a service account, so no files are accessible by it unless I give it access.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check your settings.yml file the oauth_score should be oauth_scope:

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive

you can check here [I can see only files created with my script pydrive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66902469/i-can-see-only-files-created-with-my-script-pydrive) for more detail